# Reduce code duplication for updating values in realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have a class which hold versions of different classes which are saved in Realm. This is the class:

```
class Versions: Object{
    @objc dynamic var versionY = 0
    @objc dynamic var versionX = 0
}
```

Now versionY and versionX both have there own separate class. They can update the version in class Versions with the method below. (example given for class versionY):

```
class VersionY: Object{
    func updateStoredVersion(versions: Versions) -> Bool {
        do{
            try LocalFilesManager.realm.write {
                versions.storedVersion.versionY = versions.newestVersion.versionY
            }
            return true
        }catch{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have alot of different classes in Versions, I would like to know if I can update the version in just 1 method to prevent code duplication. I use the method above for class VersionX (and every other class) just and only to update the value in Realm. I do not know how I can accomplish code duplication since Swift uses pass by value. I tried looking at generics but I do not understand that topic yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Swift 4**, you can use keypaths to access or set properties on objects. If you make each class for which you store the version inherit the following protocol, you can specify the keypath at which to store the version for that class.

```
protocol VersionedObject {
    static var versionKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Versions, Int> { get }

    func updateStoredVersion(versions: Versions, newVersion: Int) -> Bool
}

extension VersionedObject {
    func updateStoredVersion(versions: Versions, newVersion: Int) -> Bool {
        do {
            try LocalFilesManager.realm.write {
                versions[keyPath: Self.versionKeyPath] = newVersion
            }
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

An example class X, which should store its version in Versions.versionX, could then look like this:

```
class X: VersionedObject {
    static var versionKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Versions, Int> = \.versionX

    // Rest of your code
}
```